# NLTagger.requestAssets(for: language, tagScheme: .lemma) never returns

Tags: ios, swift, nlp

I am new to NLP. I need to Lemmatise a sentence. But the request for assets never returns. Here is the code:

```
if !NLTagger.availableTagSchemes(for: .word, language: .english).contains(.lemma) {
    NLTagger.requestAssets(for: .english, tagScheme: .lemma) { result, error in
        print("Never reaches here")
    }
}
```

I tried this on simulator. It never returns any response. Do I need to enable any settings to make it start working?